# jQuery grepping an array[]

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm not having much luck here.

I've got a straightforward array and I'm searching by one field of that array. I originally had them set up as key : values, but I wasn't able to return the data to a variable correctly for some reason.

My code (including a couple of array elements for good measure) is as follows:

```
var laptopsArray = []; 
laptopsArray[0] = ['123','Missing','CON','L'];
laptopsArray[1] = ['124', 'Home', 'BAT', 'I'];
laptopsArray[2] = ['125', 'Missing', 'CON', 'O'];

laptops = [];
for (i = 0; i < laptopsArray.length; i++) {
    $.grep( laptopsArray[i], function( n, i ) {
    laptops.push ( n === 'BAT');
    });
}

console.log(laptops);
```

Searching for 'BAT' (as above) returns the following in the console:

```
[false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false]
```

This is of course complete tosh and not what I'm expecting. Obviously it's iterating by each leaf of each array element. Then spitting out true or false. Right? In reality, what I'm asking it to kindly give me is the array index.

http://jsfiddle.net/rmacd/YUsBR/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.grep` creates an array based on conditions you use to look through another array

You want

```
var newArray= $.grep( laptopsArray, function( n, i ) {
      /* return true or false using a test*/
      return $.inArray( 'BAT', n) !=-1;
  })
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/raZBd/)**</kbd>

Comment: Wow. Just like that. Here I was going to do a few other things this evening, thinking like any other forum that the replies would come in hours... literally seconds, more like. Thank you! So, in other words, I should have been looking at what the output of $.grep was going to give me - in this case, another array. That makes a bit more sense.

Comment: when in doubt...jQuery API has great docs and some examples for every method

Comment: and yes...well constructed questions like yours that presnt a concise problem and an attempt to solve with accompanying code, get answered quick here.

Answer (score 1):

```
laptops = $.grep(laptopsArray, function(arr) {
    return ~$.inArray("BAT", arr);
});
```

The `$.grep` is basically jQuery's version of `Array.prototype.filter`. So you'll want to grep the outer array, and return the result of checking each nested array for the value.

---

Here's how it looks in native, ECMAScript 5 code:

```
laptops = laptopsArray.filter(function(arr) {
    return ~arr.indexOf("BAT");
});
```

---

The `~` trick is just a shorter way of making sure the test didn't return `-1`. If it did, it's converted to `0`, which is falsey.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered storing this in objects instead, it seems like it would be much more suitable. It seems like each laptop has the same attributes and it also looks like they have an id each. I would suggest something like this.

```
var laptops = []; 
laptops[0] = {
    id: 123,
    x: 'Missning',
    y: 'CON',
    z: 'L'
};
laptops[1] = {
    id: 124,
    x: 'Home', 
    y: 'BAT', 
    z: 'I'
};
laptops[2] = {
    id: 125,
    x:'Missing', 
    y: 'CON', 
    z:'O'
};

var result = $.grep(laptops, function (x) { return x.y === 'BAT' });
console.log(result);
console.log(result.length === 0); //Empty?
```

Obviously you should use better keys than `x`, `y` and `z`.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YUsBR/1/).

**EDIT:** This approach also has better time complexity as the lookup in the objects is `O(1)` thus the complexity of the whole script is `O(n)` vs `O(n^2)` for the array in array solution